# how to conditionally append element in D3 .enter() function

Tags: d3.js

All:

I wonder how to append different elements in D3 `.data().enter()`, for example:

If I want to append table column, but instead append every column as td I want the first column as th, so the code looks like:

```
tbody.append("tr").selectAll("anyplcaeholder").data([1,2,3,4])
     .enter()
// I do not know how to do this folloing
```

Any idea?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use this:

```
var table = d3.select('body').append('table');

var tr = table.selectAll('tr')
    .data([1,2,3,4,5]).enter()
    .append('tr');

tr.append('th').html(function(d) { return d; });  // add your condition here
tr.append('td').html(function(d) { return "&nbsp;"; });  // if you need more
tr.append('td').html(function(d) { return "&nbsp;"; });  // columns with data
```

This code give you something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr> .....
```

The [right way](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/irregular/) to add column header to a table

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/edffw1ka/) the working jsFiddle

Comment: Thanks, so you mean we have to manually figure this out rather than use loop?

Comment: No. D3 is intended to prevent loop use. You can make all the table without need of loop. Your case it's particular. The last 3 lines make a custom row and D3 make the rest of table with your data.